# Tabular help in CV

Tags: tables, cv

```
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}August 2017\\December 2017
\end{tabular}

\textsc{} & CEO of \textsc{Company 1}
\newline
\footnotesize{Description of CEO position etc..}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

\end{tabular}

% ---- %


\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Summer 2017\\2016, 2015
\end{tabular}

\textsc{} & Sales Assistant at \textsc{Company 2}
\newline
\footnotesize{Delivered exceptional customer service etc..}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

\end{tabular}
```

My problem is that the line that separates the dates from the work description, is not centered underneath each other and I don't know how to solve this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a fixed length for the first column of your used table:

```
\newlength{\datecolumn}
\setlength{\datecolumn}{2.5cm} % defines length for first column in table
```

To be able to change it fast for all involved tables I added a  new length variable `\datecolumn` and used it in the table with `p{\datecolumn}`.

You only need to add

```
%\end{tabular}
%
%\begin{tabular}{p{\datecolumn}|p{11cm}} % <============================
```

if you need a page break, because environment `tabular` can not go over two pages ...

So with the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\datecolumn}
\setlength{\datecolumn}{2.5cm} % defines length for first column in table

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{\datecolumn}|p{11cm}} % <=============================
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}August 2017\\December 2017
  \end{tabular}
  \textsc{} & CEO of \textsc{Company 1}
  \newline
  \footnotesize{Description of CEO position etc..}\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
%\end{tabular}
%
%\begin{tabular}{p{\datecolumn}|p{11cm}} % <============================
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Summer 2017\\2016, 2015
  \end{tabular}
  \textsc{} & Sales Assistant at \textsc{Company 2}
  \newline
  \footnotesize{Delivered exceptional customer service etc..}\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer... Just the less changes but I don't really like it.
I changed your first column to the fixed size p{3cm} instead of r

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}|p{11cm}}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}August 2017\\December 2017
\end{tabular}

\textsc{} & CEO of \textsc{Company 1}
\newline
\footnotesize{Description of CEO position etc..}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

\end{tabular}

% ---- %


\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}|p{11cm}}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Summer 2017\\2016, 2015
\end{tabular}

\textsc{} & Sales Assistant at \textsc{Company 2}
\newline
\footnotesize{Delivered exceptional customer service etc..}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You probably had not an answer yet because you did not provided a MWE ([I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/120578)).

Output:

[image]